# Food menu list automatically split into 2 columns

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I want to achieve a food menu that looks like this (screenshot), split into 2 columns.
[image: Example of food menu]

So the question is: Is there any possible way to automate it? A la just **insert foods into one list and it automatically splits it into 2 columns**.

Best Regards

Comment: Are you hardcoding the data or do you receive an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with flexbox or with the css property column-count.

Please check this(column-count): https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp

Or this(flexbox): https://flexbox.help/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if this was a React Project for example, you just make a component for the menu Item, and you make the container flex.

Either way, in HTML, lets say your structure is like this:

```
<div class="menu-container">
<div class="menu-item">

</div>
<div class="menu-item">

</div>
<div class="menu-item">

</div>
<div class="menu-item">

</div>
<div class="menu-item">

</div>
<div class="menu-item">

</div>
<div class="menu-item">

</div>
<div class="menu-item">

</div>
```

Then, for css you just need:

```
   .menu-container { 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.menu-item {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

The explanation is the following, the parent is a flexbox, which will display elements in a row fashion.

Each child has a flex-basis of 50%, meaning that each item will ocupy a 50% of the parent container and after that it will break a new row.

I recommend this useful site which has all of the most important properties of flexbox very well explained

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/